# Sql to order employees with their max salary

Tags: sql, database, performance

I have an EMPL table and SALARY table with usual foreign key relation. How can I get an list of employees order by their max salary? I am thinking along the line :

```
select e.*, s.salary 
  from EMPL e 
 inner join SALARY s on e.emp_id = s.emp_id
 order by s.salary
```

But how to put `max(salary)` in the `order by`?

Comment: Please show us your attempt to solve it. We can work off that.

Comment: Which database? What have you tried? What does it have to do with performance?

Comment: Please make up your mind and don't change your question all the time.

Comment: @mishik, question is updated.

Comment: Please add table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: @javaguy: I am not sure what you mean by: *how to put max(salary) in the order by*. Please try to improve your question and we may be able to help you. It would be best to add example data.

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.*, s.salary
from empl e
left join salary s on e.emp_id = s.emp_id
order by s.salary desc
```